# How to call another fetch after the response has come from previous fetch call in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There are two fetch statements and I want to execute the second one only after the response has come from the first one ->

```
    function CreateRide(userId){
    const baseUrl = "138.197.99.29:7000/createRide";
    var reqObj = {};
    var responseObj = {"success":false};
    let url = 'http://138.197.99.29:7000/createRide?lat=122.254&lng=14.144&vehicleID=vufn414&time=test';
    fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (data) {
            responseObj.success = true;
            console.log(data.rideID);
            return data.rideID;
        })
    .catch(function (error) {

            responseObj.success = false;
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

and ->

```
function StartRide(rideId){
    const baseUrl = "138.197.99.29:7000/createRide";
    var reqObj = {};
    var responseObj = {"success":false};
    let url = 'http://138.197.99.29:7000/startRide?rideID=' + rideId;
    fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (data) {
            responseObj.success = true;
            console.log(data);
            return data.success;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            responseObj.success = false;
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

and I want to execute StartRide after the response has come from CreateRide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the promise you have in `CreateRide`, but *returning* the result of calling `fetch().then().catch()` so you can use the chain where you call the function. Then use

```
CreateRide(/*...*/).then(result => StartRide(/*...*/)).catch(/*...error handler...*/);
```

Here's where you add the `return`:

```
function CreateRide(userId){
    const baseUrl = "138.197.99.29:7000/createRide";
    var reqObj = {};
    var responseObj = {"success":false};
    let url = 'http://138.197.99.29:7000/createRide?lat=122.254&lng=14.144&vehicleID=vufn414&time=test';
    return fetch(url)                                  // <=======
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (data) {
            responseObj.success = true;
            console.log(data.rideID);
            return data.rideID;
        })
    .catch(function (error) {

            responseObj.success = false;
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

---

Side note: This is *somewhat* a matter of style/debate, but also consider not having `CreateRide` eat the error; instead, propagate errors (e.g., when returning the promise, don't have a `catch`) and then handle errors at the outermost level you can.

---

Side note 2: Also a matter of style, but **overwhelmingly**, in JavaScript, the convention is that functions that are not constructor functions start with a lower-case letter, e.g. `createRide` and `startRide`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also how can I know if both the functions have been executed as I need to change my state variables after that ( I am developing a small project in React Native)

Comment: @PravandanChand: It's exactly the same concept: Return the promise from `StartRide` and then use a `then` handler on it. When you return a promise from a `then` handler, the promise `then` creates is slaved to the promise you return. So if you return the one from `StartRide`, then `CreateRide(/*...*/).then(result => StartRide(/*...*/)).then(result => /* update state variables */).catch(/*...error handler...*/);`

Comment: @TJCrowder Thank you very much :)